# How to handle change event while opening other apps or web tabs with Java script in SAP UI5/Fiori

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have one change function in my sap.m.Input field. If I added some value ex.1234 and selected tab or enter or I changed mouse to next input or mouse clicked some other where its showing some validation error .When its showing error I am deleting that value which is in Input .Its working fine for all conditions.

Requirement :
If user has added some value in the input and opened some outside applications like Outlook or he opened other web pages the error message is coming and the value from input also deleting. If user should open any other apps or any other web pages the function should not trigger.

How to control it, Please help me.

Thanks in advance!!

If user has added some value in the input and opened other apps like Outlook, excel or he opened any other browser tabs the function should not trigger

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible as the change event is always triggered the input loses focuses.